# Is Structured Streaming real-time stream processing engine?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-flink

We know Flink is a really real time streaming processing engine, which can deal with records just when they arrive, and we also know that spark streaming is a micro-batch streaming processing engine.

However we also know that spark released the structured-streaming, how about it? Is it also a really real time streaming processing engine just like Flink ,which can deal with the record immediately when it arrives instead of micro-batch or still using a micro-batch mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is Structured Streaming real-time stream processing engine?

**TL;DR** No. Or yes. Depends on definition of "real-time stream processing engine".

Up to the **2.3.0-SNAPSHOT** (current [master](https://github.com/apache/spark)), Structured Streaming uses micro-batches and nothing seems to suggest it's going to be different in the versions to come.

### Deep Dive Into Structured Streaming's Streaming Query Engine

[StreamExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/StreamExecution.scala) (the execution environment for a streaming query) [starts a separate thread of execution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/StreamExecution.scala#L247) that checks whether new records are available.

Once started, the `microBatchThread` (which is a regular Java's `java.lang.Thread` object) executes [runBatches](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/StreamExecution.scala#L211) that [starts execution every trigger interval](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/StreamExecution.scala#L294).

Going through the code reveals the internal execution engine for streaming queries that **does** batches every trigger.

My understanding is that nothing has really changed as far as micro-batching is concerned. It was like this in Spark Streaming and is used in Structured Streaming too.

---

*Shameless plug*: You may want to explore the subject in more details reading [my gitbook about Structured Streaming](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-StreamExecution.html) which I'm writing exactly for the purpose to understand the very low-level details. Comments welcome.

Comment: Hi Jacek, how do you think about the [SPARK-20928](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20928)? It would change the way the spark dealing with the records from micro-batch to one by one ? That's to say spark would deal with the record immediately when it arrives?

Comment: In SPARK-20928, Michael Armbrust, Spark SQL lead, talks about a "an alternative StreamExecution that processes continuously" meaning without microbatches, as they said during the Spark Summit. But as you said it must depend on the definition of "real-time stream processing engine". Looking forward to seeing the future of Sructured streaming!
I love your gitbook, btw

Comment: @polomarcus Yes. I heard that too and that stroke me a little bit as it's against what I could've found in the code. Perhaps I mis-interpreted things. I'm working on having the entire picture.

Answer (score 2):

In the last [Spark Summit's intro](https://spark-summit.org/2017/events/expanding-apache-spark-use-cases-in-22-and-beyond/) (SF June 2017), they talked about "Continuous pipeline" and a new execution model **without microbatches** with checkpointing for latency < 1ms (instead of 10-100ms that is possible today), see slide 35 and [Spark-20928](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20928).

But the targeted version is 
**2.3.0.**

Comment: I saw the Spark-20928 , however it seem there is no difference between proposal getBatch and the original one, how it can reflect the "without microbatches " architecture and achieve a less 1 ms latency? just deal with the events immediately when they arrive instead of aggregating the events into the micro-batch?